# Check if user visits own profile in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I have a route that finds user by id. I want to show different content on the profile depending on whether the user is visiting his own profile or another users profile.

The method in the Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/u/{id}", name="profile_show")
 * @ParamConverter("user", class="UserBundle:User")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction(User $user)
{
    $auth = $this->getUser();

    if ($user->getId() == $auth->getId()) {
        $auth->addRole('ROLE_PROFILE_OWNER');
    }

    return array(
        'user' => $user
    );
}
```

The output in Twig:

```
        {% if is_granted('ROLE_PROFILE_OWNER') %}
            <p>This is my profile</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>This is not my profile</p>
        {% endif %}
```

The role shows up on the user if I do {{ dump(app.user) }} yet it outputs the text that it is not my profile. Anyone knows why this does not work?

Also I have no clue if this is actually the right way to do things like this. I want to follow best practice so if this is totally wrong please enlighten me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe the is_granted() function checks the roles of the user that are cached within the session. So adding a role to the user doesn't necessarily update the session unless you've somehow taken care of that in your code. What about using something like {% if $user.hasRole('...') %} in your template instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials check is happening before `showAction()` is executed, so the `$auth->addRole('ROLE_PROFILE_OWNER');` line never runs. That is why you always get the "this is not your profile" message.

Also, you should not use user roles to do this kind of profile ownership check. Instead just compare the logged-in user's `id` (stored in Session) and the profile `user_id`. If they are not the same throw an `AccessDeniedException()`.

Take a look at the documentation [Securing a controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-a-controller) and [Session Management](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) pages.

Comment: I do not want to secure the controller itself. Just hide certain content from the view if the user_id does not match the logged in user's id. Either way I think this answers my question about how to do this the right way. It should be fine to just compare the session user id and profile user id in twig and show that certain content only if they match.